# in gnu / linux how can i scan a file from an initial string (foo) to final string (bar)

Tags: bash, awk, grep

in gnu / linux how can i scan a file from an initial string (foo) to final string (bar)

I'd like to use linux tools (grep, awk, gawk, etc) to scan a file from an initial string in the file, foo, to a final string in the same file, (bar); so that i can do something with that output. The scenario can present for instance when i have to deal with a huge file and is better to do it in little pieces so as to avoid too much loading to ram.

i've tried using browser but the original file does not load because is too big (40MG), the same applies to text editors (notepads....), i can edit and view the file in the dev server via vim. at least

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Are you looking for [`csplit`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/csplit.html)?

Answer (score 3):

```
$ sed -n '/foo/,/bar/p' file
```

the same you can do with `awk` and more...

Answer (score 1):

for the time being, using `grep i can do something like this:

```sh
grep "\stringRegExpToSearch" -A howManyLinesAfterFirst encounter myFileToScan.txt
```